# Why isn't .gitignore ignoring .sass-cache?

Tags: git

My project looks like this:

[image]

**.gitignore:**

```
/node_modules
/dist
/.tmp
/.sass-cache
.sass-cache
/bower_component
```

No idea why, but `.sass-cache` is still being staged:

```
User@User-PC MINGW64 /e/alex/istagingadmindashboard/frontEnd (deve)
$ git add .

User@User-PC MINGW64 /e/alex/istagingadmindashboard/frontEnd (deve)
$ git status
On branch deve
Your branch is up-to-date with 'remotes/origin/deve'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   .sass-cache/a1ee9da9874bbf1b217c6f2a5cd8c2c7c5ee78fe/main.scssc
        modified:   app/scripts/building/uploadPage.js
        modified:   app/styles/main.scss
        modified:   app/views/building/uploadproject.html
```

Any ideas of why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `.gitignore` file was likely updated after that particular folder's contents were staged.  To complete the circle, perform `git rm -r --cached .sass-cache/`.

Also, you only need one entry for it in `.gitignore`; preferably, one with a slash at either the front or the end to denote it as a directory.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you already uploaded the folder .sass-cache to the server. You see that it says `modified`. You have to do:

```
git rm .sass-cache/*
git commit -a -m "removed folder"
git push origin master
```

The next time you do `git status` you won't see the folder.

Also, you don't need to add both

```
/.sass-cache
.sass-cache
```

Only the last one is enough

Answer (score 3):

These files are *already* tracked by git, and hence your `.gitignore` will have no effect on those. However, new, untracked files will be ignored. See [the gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to remove already committed sass-cache files from your repo -- and are on Linux. You can run the find command in the Terminal, from the root of your repo file:

```
$_ `find . -name "*.scssc" -exec git rm -f {} \;`
```

Afterwards commit:

```
$_ git commit -m "Remove .scssc cache files."
```

Then add these lines to your .gitignore with `$_ nano .gitignore`:

```
styles/.sass-cache/*
styles/.sass-cache
.sass-cache/
*.css.map
```

Answer (score 0):

From the wiki:

> If you already have a file checked in, and you want to ignore it, Git will not ignore the file if you add a rule later. In those cases, you must untrack the file first, by running the following command in your terminal:
>
> git rm --cached