# .gitignore is not ignoring one specific folder

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I am developing a React Native project so there is a lot of crap that I don't actually need to push to the git repo. The `node_modules` is at the **.gitignore** file and it do not go to the repo as normal. The problem is that I do not need a folder called *build* too, that is inside of another folder called *ios*. So I created two **.gitignore** files, one I placed at the main directory with `node_modules` written, and the other one at the *ios* folder, with `build/` written.

The problem is that only the node_modules folder is ignored as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbfLC.png).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't .gitignore ignoring .sass-cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449222/why-isnt-gitignore-ignoring-sass-cache)

Answer (score 0):

Your build folder is being ignored, as is your node_modules folder. The reason you're getting that specific message is that you instructed git to add it and it was warning you that it couldn't.

```
git add *
```

Means add each file in this folder to git. If you want to add all the untracked files and all changes, use:

```
git add .
    or
git add -a
```

Which means to add the current directory and all available children.

You can move both rules into a single .gitignore file at the root if you'd like, the rules will still work. You can also confirm that the rules are working by using:

```
git check-ignore -v [path]
```

Which will output the rule it is using to exclude the path if it is ignored.